# Angular 4 dates using pipe in not US order

Tags: angular

I have date '24-11-2017' in European order(dd-mm-yy), but the standard in Angular is US date order(month-day-year). How to change it?

```
constructor(private datepipe: DatePipe ) { }

function showDay(date: any) {
  let value = this.datePipe.transform( date , 'dd');
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `date` is a date format, this should work :

```
constructor(private datepipe: DatePipe ) { }

function showDay(date: any) {
  let value = this.datePipe.transform( date , 'MM-dd-yyyy');
  console.log(value);
}
```

You need to precise the format in the `transform` function.
If you need more details, check the [official angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with just the date pipe because `DD-MM-YYYY` isn't valid for a javascript date. You can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to format your date into `MM-DD-YYYY` so it can be used by the date pipe.

```
function showDay(date: any) {
    date = moment.utc(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    let value = this.datePipe.transform( date , 'DD');
}
```

However since you are using the datepipe within your typescript code, you could just use moment.

```
function showDay(date: any) {
    let value = moment.utc(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD');
}
```